# Are node's child processes "much" slower?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

Consider the following code that approximates pi:

```
// filename: pi.js
function approx_pi(from, to) {
    var pi = 0;
    var dx = 0.0000000005;
    for(var x = from; x < to; x += dx) {
        pi += 4 / (1 + x * x);
    }
    return pi * dx;
}

var min = Infinity;
var max = -1;
var avg = 0;

for(var itr = 0; itr < 10; ++itr) {
    var start = process.hrtime();
    var pi = approx_pi(0, 1);
    var diff = process.hrtime(start);

    var duration = diff[0] + diff[1] * 1e-9;

    min = (duration <= min) ? duration : min;
    max = (duration >= max) ? duration : max;
    avg += duration;
}

avg /= 10;

min = min.toFixed(3);
max = max.toFixed(3);
avg = avg.toFixed(3);

console.log("Time: min = %ss, max = %ss , avg = %ss", min, max, avg);
```

Also consider this code that runs the file above in n child processes while n is given through command line arguments:

```
//filename: children.js
var cp = require('child_process');

var n = parseInt(process.argv[2]);

for(var k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
    cp.fork('pi.js');
}
```

When running `node pi.js` the output is:

```
Time: min = 19.113s, max = 22.220s , avg = 21.152s
```

A similar result comes from running `node children.js 1` (which is expected)

```
Time: min = 17.323s, max = 21.465s , avg = 19.979s
```

Stuff starts getting weird (to my own expectations at least) when more than one child is forked. Here is the output after running `node children.js 2` :

```
Time: min = 29.824s, max = 41.050s , avg = 35.136s
Time: min = 30.036s, max = 40.791s , avg = 35.246s
```

each child took at least 14 more seconds than the single versions. It got even worse on running 4 children with `node children.js 4` , each took about 37 seconds more to finish:

```
Time: min = 55.878s, max = 68.047s , avg = 58.845s
Time: min = 52.760s, max = 69.168s , avg = 58.880s
Time: min = 57.151s, max = 69.113s , avg = 58.956s
Time: min = 50.790s, max = 70.344s , avg = 59.546s
```

These tests ran on a machine with Core i5 2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz (4 cores visible to the os), and a 4GB RAM, with both: Windows 7 running node v4.2.3 and Ubuntu14.04 running node v5.4.1. Each os showed that each of the children ran on its own core and each had the same amount of allocated memory (about 9MB).

According to the node documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options): **"Each process has it's own memory, with their own V8 instances"**. So one would expect that each child should perform as good as the single process.

Are my expectations misguided and this is the expected behavior or what's is going on?

Comment: Your test should really loop at least 10 times and then report the min, max and average times. This gives V8 time to compile your code (the first run will always be the slowest). Also, Date.now() is not very precise (so it'll tend to overestimate the time).

Comment: @JDB I averaged over 10 iterations like you pointed out and used `process.hrtime` instead of `Date.now`. The data didn't differ much though.

Answer (score 2):

You are running 4 processes in parallel on a CPU with [2 cores (4 threads)](http://ark.intel.com/products/52224/Intel-Core-i5-2410M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz) and then measuring the actual time rather than the CPU time. Of course each process will take longer... you can't run an infinite number of processes on a limited number of cores and expect the run time to be the same as running a single process on multiple cores. (If anyone ever figures out how to do that, then cybersecurity is toast.)

You might expect 2 processes running on 2 cores to run in the same time as a single process (which must run on a single core), but the reality is often not quite the same as theory. It's very possible that your 2 processes are actually sharing time on the same core. There's no easy way to guarantee that each process will get it's own core since those kinds of details are almost always abstracted away from your control.

Comment: I disabled the hyper-threading on my machine so that the two cores that are visible to the os are actually two cores not two threads on the same core. I then ran `node children.js 1` and `node chidren.js 2`, the difference this time was about +10s (a little less than with hyper-threading, which was +14s), but it's still a lot! I tried the same task with c++ using mpi and the difference was about +3.3s! do you think that the extra +6.7s in js is merely due to c++ speed over js?

Comment: You still can't guarantee that the processes each ran on a separate core. That's the clincher... are they running on separate cores (truly parallel) or are they sharing a core (reducing the speed of each)? The fact that a single child process runs in the same time as it's parent would suggest that child processes are not slower. The speed differential with C++ doesn't seem relevant to me... I'd guess that C++ runs faster anyway since it's compiled to native byte code while Node is using a JIT compiler, so the percent faster would be a better comparison than the raw numbers.

Comment: Well, according to the os task manager, they are running on separate cores. When I kill one of the processes, the utilization % of one core drops while the other remains at 100%. But the thing is that when a single child is running, it takes a whole core for itself, the os processes and the parent process share the other core. When two children run on both cores, they can't have them all for them self, they share them with the other os processes. This explains why they take longer, but the magnitude of the difference is what's bugging me!

Comment: I think it's a good research topic, but I don't think your tests are really proving that there's a difference or what the difference is. C++ is extremely optimized and lean code compared to Node, which is why game programmers still prefer it. I think you'd need to do some more testing before declaring that Node child processes actually take longer.

Comment: I guess so. I think these tests need to be run in a more controlled environment to be able to deduce anything form them. Thanks for your help!